# How to disable animation while 3 finger swiping to desktop?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to get into Desktop 2 it's much faster than swiping three fingers to that desktop.

Is it possible to disable the animation with 3 finger swipe?

Answer (score 2):

The animation speed is proportional to the speed of the swipe. If you swipe fast enough, the animation will be even faster than the one used with Ctrl+2.